# How To Setup AWS CodePipeline to Deploy .Net6 Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-code-deploy

I don't know whther its possible to deploy to Lambda Function using Code Deploy in CodePipeline as I don't see any Target there.
if its possible How we can set it in aws console?

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know whther its possible to deploy to Lambda Function using Code Deploy in CodePipeline

Yes it is.

There are various ways you can achieve this. The most straight forward way is to use CodePipeline that is triggered by a CodeCommit repository for a  [SAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html) package.

CodeDeploy will deploy the SAM package in a pipeline stage which will include your Lambda function.

Here is [a tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-simple-codecommit.html) from AWS Docs.